# spring-hibernate3 with hibernate-core-4.1.2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I want to set open session in view pattern controlled by Spring. I am using Hibernate 4.1.2. Now if I add spring-hibernate3 in pom.xml eventually it add its dependency hibernate-3.2.5.ga. I think I can not have these two hibernates at a time.

If I want to use spring-hibernate3 should I remove the hibernate-core-4.1.2.jar?

This is my pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-datetime</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.jqwicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>jqwicket</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you remove the hibernate-core 4.1.2 dependency from your pom.xml file, you'll only have the hibernate3 jar in your classpath.

But since spring-hibernate seems to be pretty old (from the Spring point of view, the latest is [2.0.8 version](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.springframework%22%20AND%20a%3a%22spring-hibernate3%22) and lastest Spring Core is 3.1.1)

But I think you can use the open session in view pattern with your current setup, since spring-orm-3.1.1 supports Hibernate4; take a look at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/support/package-summary.html.